# Remove 'lone' lines from a text file

Tags: bash, text-processing

I've got a text file looking something like this:

```
>>>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

>>>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

>>>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

>>>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

>>>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

i.e. a file consisting of "groups" with headers starting with >>>. As you can see, some groups are empty - consisting of only a header and I'd like them to be removed. Result should be:

```
>>>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

>>>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

>>>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Is there any convenient way of accomplishing it, preferably using standard bash tolls s.a awk, sed, grep, etc?

Thankyouverymuch in advance!

Comment: & What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
awk '/.+/ { if (h) {print h; c++; print}}
     /^>>>/ {h=$0; c=0}
     /^$/ { if (c>0) print; h=false}'
```

But next time you should show something that you tried already

Comment: Thank you! This works, is elegant and clear enough for me to understand without further explanation (no need to bother @anishsane).


As for the reason for not _showing something that I've already tried_, I am total noob at awk and only used it for simple column manipulation and simply couldn't come up with anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{if (split($0,a,"\n")>1)print}' RS= ORS=$'\n\n' test.txt
```

Comment: After you update the question about your coding attempts, please comment on this answer, so that I would put the explanation for this code.

Answer (score 1):

With sed you can write this:

```
sed -n '/^>>>/{h;n;/^$/!{H;g;p};d};/^>>>/!p;' file.txt
```

or if you are sure that all blocks are separated with two newlines:

```
sed -n '/^>>>/{h;n;/^$/!{H;g;p};d};p;' file.txt
```